# Как получить дату из числа

Tags: время, форматирование, chromium, unixtimestamp

Хочу получать дату и время открытой страницы из Яндекс Браузера.
Файл `History` по пути `C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Yandex\YandexBrowser\User Data\Default`. Открываю через `DB Browser`. Перехожу в таблицу `Urls`. Там есть столбец `last_visit_time`, как показано на скрине ниже.
[image: DB Browser]

Но проблема вот в чём:
13329084303079951 в Unix-формате - это Wed, 09 Mar 44208 21:45:07 в GMT-формате.
Как получить дату из этого числа?

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ поддержки Яндекс Браузера:**
Яндекс Браузер сделан на основе Chromium и повторяет значения в столбце last_visit_time. Попробуйте, пожалуйста, воспользоваться [этой инструкцией](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458406/what-is-the-format-of-chromes-timestamps).

**Перевод ответа:**
Временная метка [Google Chrome] отформатирована как количество микросекунд, прошедших с января 1601 года.

**Сконвертировать в читабельную дату можно следующим запросом:**

```
SELECT
datetime(13329084303079951 / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

Comment: Вы можете засчитать ваш ответ, для этого [нажмите галочку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) слева от ответа.

Comment: Почка что не могу. Выдаёт сообщение "Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 2 дня". @VadikSirekanyan

Comment: Ок, тогда засчитайте его через два дня :) А писать в теме, что вопрос закрыт это излишне, поэтому я это убрал.